# How to visualise a geodesic for a particular manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic, general-relativity

I always struggle to understand how to visualise a geodesic. When given a metric I can easily deduce the geodesic equations but I do not know how to visualise them. For instance consider a torus parametrised
as follows: $$ x = (A + B \cos θ) \cos \phi, \space y = (A + B \cos θ) \sin \phi , \space z = B \sin θ, $$ where $A$
and $B$ are two constant parameters.

We can define the metric as follows:

$$ds^2 = B^2
dθ^2 + (A + B \cos θ)^2
dφ^2
$$

I know the geodesic equations are as follows:

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}((A + B \cos θ)^2
\dot \phi) = 0$$

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}(2B^2 \dotθ) = −2(A + B \cos θ)B \sin θ \dot \phi^2$$

My question is how could one look at those geodesic equations (or better still any geodesic equations ) and understand the path of the geodesic.

Comment: It takes some work, but Clairaut's relation tells all that is needed for a qualitative picture. In do Carmo's book on curves and surfaces.

Comment: No easy way. Solve the equations numerically and plot them. You can ask about how to do this in various programming languages on stack overflow.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1967147.pdf